# With the last update of the xgboost function I got an annoying error related to the internal function xgb.iter.update

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

This is the code I am implementing:

```
## 7.1) Working only with the PCA components from 1 to 5 (Set 1) ----

## |¬ Defining a extreme gradient boosting model of classification (only PC 1-5)

xgb.training.features <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(baked.training[, -1]))
setinfo(object = xgb.training.features, name = 'label', 
        info = as.numeric(as.data.frame(baked.training)[, 1]) - 1)`

## Selecting the best hyperparameters (1)

hyper_grid1 <-  expand.grid(num_class = 5, booster = "gbtree",
                            eta = c(.1, .2, .4, .6, .8),
                            max_depth = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
                            min_child_weight = c(.1, .5, 1, 2, 4),
                            alpha = 0,
                            lamda = 0,
                            gamma = 0,
                            objective = "multi:softmax",
                            merror = 0,
                            trees = 0)

par.selector <- function(hyper_grid, data)
{
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(hyper_grid)))
  {
    m <- xgb.cv(params = list(num_class = hyper_grid[["num_class"]][i],
                              booster = "gbtree"[i],
                              eta = hyper_grid[["eta"]][i],
                              max_depth = hyper_grid[["max_depth"]][i],
                              min_child_weight = 
                                hyper_grid[["min_child_weight"]][i],
                              alpha = hyper_grid[["alpha"]][i],
                              lamda = hyper_grid[["lamda"]][i],
                              gamma = hyper_grid[["gamma"]][i],
                              objective = hyper_grid[["objective"]][[i]]), 
                data = data, 
                nrounds = 4000, 
                nfold = 10,
                prediction = T,
                showsd = T,
                stratified = T,
                verbose = T,
                early_stopping_rounds = 50,
                metrics = "merror", 
                nthread = 3,
                obj = "multi:softmax")
    
    hyper_grid$merror[i] <- min(m$evaluation_log$test_merror_mean)
    hyper_grid$trees[i] <- m$best_iteration
  }
  
  hyper_grid
}

test <- par.selector(hyper_grid = hyper_grid1, data = xgb.training.features)
```

This code results in the following error after the firs execution of the xgb.cv function:

```
Error in xgb.iter.update(fd$bst, fd$dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) :
[09:23:35] src/gbm/gbm.cc:24: Unknown gbm type NA
```

I have read the documentation, and I am following all the specifications. I need to solve this problem. The code worked well for the previous release of the package.

In this case, I defined a function that uses different combinations of parameters (generated with expand.grid), and I am retrieving the best combination of parameters. Well, that is what I am intending to do.

But I am getting the above mentioned error. How to resolve it?